# Python function that turns a number into binary

Tags: python, arrays, function, binary

I know that in python there are certain functions like `bin` that turn
decimal numbers into binary numbers. I would like to build one myself. I have tried the following:

```
def binary(n):
    bina = ''
    B = []
    if n == 0:
        bina = '0'
    else: 
        while n>0:
            x = 0
            while 2**x<n:
                x = x+1
                B.append(x-1)
                n = n-2**(x-1)
```

The problem is that when I have the exponents with base 2 in the array `B` I don’t know how to actually read them so that I obtain the actual binary number made of ones and zeroes. How can I make the code above work?

before someone says that my question was already asked, my question is how can I **make the code above work**,I know that there are other methods to make a binary convertion in python, but I would like to know what's wrong with mine and possibly make my code work.

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Convert-Numbers-to-Binary/

Comment: @omercotkd I know that, but how I can implement it into my code was my question

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Kind of, isn’t there a way to simply use the code I have published and get the binary by reading array `B`?

Comment: @Emilio - No, because don't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def make_binary(num):
    binary = ''
    while num > 0:
        binary = str(num % 2) + binary
        num = num // 2
    return binary
print(make_binary(15))
```

Comment: It can also be done using bit shift and bitwise comparison:
`binary = str(num & 1) + binary` and `num = num >> 1`